# How to change yyyymmdd format to mm-dd-yyyy in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to reformat a xlsx file with column incident history (e.g. Class II : O : 20181119) yyyymmdd to mm-dd-yyyy in the dataframe but the caveat is that some cells are unequal with some with more than one Class

[image]

I tried using split and apply but I can't manipulate it to a point where I can clean it

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/blablabla')
```

I tried doing this but it only outputs NaN:

```
df['incident history'] = df['incident history'].str.split(':').tolist()
df['incident history'] = df['incident history'].str.split('\n').tolist()
```

also tried this but get a `TypeError: ("'float' object is not iterable", 'occurred at index 0')`

```
def foo(c):
   for x in c['incident history']:
       return x        
df['incident history reformed'] = df.apply(foo, axis=1)
print (df['incident history reformed'])
```

[image]

Comment: what dtype is the incident history column?  String?

Comment: (df['incident history'].dtype) shows that it is an object

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're close. The following worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd

data = ['Class II: R : 20180920','Class II: O : 20181119','Class II: D1: 20170601','Class O: D1: 20190219']

df = pd.DataFrame({"incident_history":data})

def extract_dt(dt_str):
    out_str = dt_str[dt_str.rfind(":")+1:].strip()
    return pd.to_datetime(out_str, format="%Y%m%d")

df['incident_history_reformed'] = df["incident_history"].apply(extract_dt)
```

Where `incident_history_reformed` will have a type of datetime64[ns] and thus open the door to all the datetime functionality provided by pandas.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to make it as readable as possible. 
Your date seems to always be the last 8 characters in your column `Incident history`. You can select them as you have done. Here I use negative index.

Then I convert the column of type string to a datetime using `to_datetime` [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

For sorting the dataframe, you can use `sort_values` by precising the column to sort [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
                   ["Class II : R : 20180920"],
                   ["Class II : O : 20181109"],
                   ["Class O : D1 : 20170601"],
                   ["Class O : D1 : 20190219"]],
                  columns=["Incident history"])

print(df)
#        Incident history
# 0  Class II: R: 20180920
# 1  Class II: O: 20181109
# 2  Class O: D1: 20170601
# 3  Class O: D1: 20190219

# Create a string variable containing the date
df["date"] = df["Incident history"].str[-8:]
print(df)
#         Incident history date_string
# 0  Class II: R: 20180920    20180920
# 1  Class II: O: 20181109    20181109
# 2  Class O: D1: 20170601    20170601
# 3  Class O: D1: 20190219    20190219

# Transform the date column to the type "date"
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%Y%m%d", yearfirst=True)
print(df)
#         Incident history       date
# 0  Class II: R: 20180920 2018-09-20
# 1  Class II: O: 20181109 2018-11-09
# 2  Class O: D1: 20170601 2017-06-01
# 3  Class O: D1: 20190219 2019-02-19

# Sort according to date
df = df.sort_values(by='date')
print(df)
#         Incident history       date
# 2  Class O: D1: 20170601 2017-06-01
# 0  Class II: R: 20180920 2018-09-20
# 1  Class II: O: 20181109 2018-11-09
# 3  Class O: D1: 20190219 2019-02-19

# Optional : remove the date from "Incident history"
df["Incident history"] = df["Incident history"].str[:-10]
print(df)
# Incident history       date
# 2    Class O: D1  2017-06-01
# 0    Class II: R  2018-09-20
# 1    Class II: O  2018-11-09
# 3    Class O: D1  2019-02-19
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're working with strings in `incident_history` AND the date is of format `YYYYMMDD` AND the date always shows up at the end of the string after the last `:` then you can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'incident_history': [
        'Class II:R:20180920',
        'Class II:O:20181119',
        'Class II:O:20181119',
        'Class O:D1:20170601',
        'Class O:D1:20190219',
    ],
})

def get_date(s):
    i = s.rfind(":")  # find last occurence of ":" in string
    date_string = s[i+1:]    
    return pd.to_datetime(date_string, format="%Y%m%d")

df.incident_history.apply(get_date)
```

you can one-line the above using:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.incident_history.apply(lambda x: x[x.rfind(":")+1:]), format="%Y%m%d")
```